# Matlab figure windows - getting handles

Tags: matlab

I have a for loop where I do something like:

```
figno = 1;
for i = 1:50
 h       =   figure( figno );
 figno   =   figno + 1;
 plot( x, y, '-.ob' );                
 grid on;
 xlim([1,12]);
 legend( 'x', 'y' );
 ylabel( 'Value' );
 title( 'Figure Title' );   
end

handles     =   findall( 0, 'type', 'figure' );
Fig2PDF( 'MyFile.PDF', numel( handles ) );
```

Where the function Fig2PDF is a function which reads the number of handles and looks up for all open figures and converts it to one PDF file.

But the server gives error due to 50 open windows. I was wondering whether it is possible to do the above without opening the figure window.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more: "But the server gives error due to 50 open windows.". Also, `for i=1:50;h=figure(figno);figno=figno+1;` can be written as `for i=1:50;h=figure(i)`, `figno` is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting the figure visibility to off. Shown here:

```
for i = 1:50
   h = figure(i);
   set(h,'Visible','off');
   plot(x, y,'-.ob');                
   grid on;
   xlim([1,12]);
   legend('x','y');
   ylabel('Value');
   title('Figure Title');   
end
handles = findall(0, 'type', 'figure');
Fig2PDF('MyFile.PDF', numel(handles));
```